# Using ${basedir} in NLog target creates a folder by that name

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I am using NLog.Web.AspNetCore in a Asp.Net core 2.0 project. If I use the following target:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="${basedir}/nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
```

it creates an empty folder called "${basedir}" in my application's ContentRoot folder. It puts the log file in bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0.

Why is it not substituting for ${basedir}? It works fine if I use a full path for the log folder.

I should add that I also have the following in nlog.config, inside the < nlog > element:

```
internalLogFile="${basedir}/internal-nlog.txt"
```

When there is an internal Nlog error, it writes to this file inside the folder named "${basedir}".

Comment: Have you updated to `NLog.Web.AspNetCore ver. 4.5.0-rc3` and `NLog ver. 4.5.0-rc06`, and updated your code in `Program.cs` to match https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2 (See usage of `LogManager.LoadConfiguration`)

Comment: The `internalLogFile` is very basic (to keep it simple and predictable), so it has no knowledge output layout-renderers like `${basedir}`. It is most likely the internalLogFile that creates the directory.

Comment: `${basedir}` means AppDomain.BaseDirectory. Where do you expect basedir to go ?

Comment: Created https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/253, so one can access ${aspnet-appbasepath} (Matching IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath and the old IApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath)

Comment: This is my first time using NLog. I had followed your instructions for .Net Core 2.0. It only said to install NLog.Web.AspNetCore. Now if I also try to install NLog, it says "Package restore failed. Rolling back ...". I was installing the "latest stable" for both: NLog 4.4.12 and NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.4.1.

Comment: You say "${basedir} means AppDomain.BaseDirectory". But that is where my log files go if I just use a file name without ${basedir}. ${aspnet-appbasepath} sounds like it is what I would want.

Comment: NLog is still in pre-release-stage when it comes to AspNetCore support. Though it is stable and production ready. The introduction of structured logging and conversion to Vs2017 multi-target-project has caused some delays. So right now you have to divert from "Latest Stable".

Comment: I am still confused about the relation of the NLog and NLog.Web.AspNetCore. Are both needed? Your instructions for Net Core only say to install NLog.Web.AspNetCore. But they also talk about updating NLog.

Comment: NLog.Web.AspNetCore is an extension for NLog, that depends on NLog. NLog is the core engine. NLog.Web.AspNetCore is not updated so often, so it usually depends on an old version of NLog. Therefore it is recommended to manually update to the latest NLog.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `${basedir}` folder is created, because the NLog Internal Logger is very primitive and doesn't know about layout-renders.

- **Update NLog ver. 4.6 adds support for using `${basedir}` in [internalLogFile](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/internal-logging)**

The workaround for Asp.Net.Core could be the following (Added two new lines to the [Wiki Example](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2#4-update-programcs) in `Program.cs`):

```
var appBasePath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("appbasepath", appBasePath);
var logger = LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Then you can use `${gdc:item=appbasepath}` in your `nlog.config`:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="${gdc:item=appbasepath}/Logs/nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
```

While waiting for `${aspnet-appbasepath}` to become ready.

Comment: I get 2 errors: "No overload for Set takes 2 params." & "LogManager has no LoadConfiguration method". When I installed NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.1.1, it automatically installed NLog 5.0.0-beta07, which is higher that any releases on nuget.org/packages/NLog. So I don't know what releases I should be using.

Comment: Like I wrote before: Have you updated to NLog.Web.AspNetCore ver. 4.5.0-rc3 and NLog ver. 4.5.0-rc06 ? (Have updated the code to fix the first error)

Comment: I installed those two versions. But I still get the first error. (I should have wrote "No overload for Set takes 1 argument.")

Comment: Notice that I also wrote that I have updated the code example in my answer, to fix the first error. Please copy-paste again.

Comment: Great! It works perfectly. Thanks a lot for all your help. I notice that you call CreateDefaultBuilder and then add the json files and environment variables to the config. CreateDefaultBuilder already would add those and also UserSecrets and command line arguments. It seems a bit of duplication.

Comment: Glad it works. Yes you are right about the duplication. Have now updated the Wiki and removed the duplicated config.

Comment: In .net core I prefer to use `AppContext.BaseDirectory`. GetCurrentDirectory occasionally returns C:\Windows\System32 in case of Windows Service built using TopShelf.

Comment: As a follow up to your answer, consider adding that only a few layout renderers are supported there now. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/internal-logging

Comment: @daniel.caspers The answer was written before NLog 4.6 was released, but have now update my answer.