# Using GlobalDiagnosticsContext in NLog internalLogFile

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog, .net-6.0

Is it possible to add a custom variable to the `internalLogFile` attribute in the nlog.config file, like `ProjectName` in  `internalLogFile="c:\logs\${gdc:ProjectName}\internal-nlog.txt"`?

I tried this:

```
<nlog internalLogFile="c:\logs\${gdc:ProjectName}\internal-nlog.txt">
  ...
</nlog>
```

and

```
private static void ConfigureLogging(IServiceCollection services)
{
    GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("ProjectName", "some-project-name");
    LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config");

    services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
    {
        loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(Config.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Debug);
        loggingBuilder.AddNLog();
    });
}
```

But `LoadConfiguration` throws an error (caught as first-chance exception in VS, so it's actually silently ignored):

```
System.IO.IOException: The directory name is invalid. : 'c:\logs\${gdc:ServiceRunnerFolder}'
```

I stepped through NLog code and it seems it only calls `ExpandFilePathVariables` to expand some known environment variables before setting the filename.

Is there a way to use a custom variable for this filename, without creating environment variables?

Comment: Somewhat related to [Using ${basedir} in NLog target creates a folder by that name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48958909/69809).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using ${gdc} and `GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("ProjectName", "some-project-name");` then just update the InternalLogger directly:

```cs
var projectName = "some-project-name";
NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogFile = $"c:\logs\{some-project-name}\internal-nlog.txt";
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging#example-with-internal-logging-from-code

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I found the docs, it seems it's [not possible as of NLog 5](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/internal-logging#enabling-internal-logging-using-configuration-file):

> When you configure NLog using Configuration File, you can enable
> internal logging by setting the following attribute on the 
> element:
>
> - `internalLogFile="file.txt"` - adding
>   internalLogFile cause NLog to write its internal debugging messages to
>   the specified file. This includes any exceptions that may be thrown
>   during logging.
>
>   - Note: only a few layouts are supported, as the
>     internal log needs to be as stable as possible.
>   - NLog 4.6+: Environment
>     Variables are also supported: e.g. `%appdata%` or `%HOME%`
>   - NLog 4.6+:
>     Supports renderers (without options): `${currentdir}`, `${basedir}`,
>     `${tempdir}`
>   - NLog 4.7.1+: Supports renderer (without options):
>     `${processdir}`
>   - NLog 5.0+: Supports renderers (without options):
>     `${commonApplicationDataDir}`, `${userApplicationDataDir}`,
>     `${userLocalApplicationDataDir}`